# Aus dem Kirschfestlied, “ein Lehrer (...) verful auf die Kinder” — verful wohl ein Scherz für verfiel, aber was heißt “verfallen auf die Kinder”?

Tags: meaning, translation, german-to-english, lyrics

Aus dem [Kirschfestlied](https://hussiten-kirschfest.de/kirschfestlied.html) (Seyferth, 1823):

> "und ein Lehrer von der Schul´ sann auf Rettung und verful endlich auf die Kinder"

Das Wort **verful** ist [scheinbar ein Scherz](https://books.google.de/books?id=sKidCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA146&lpg=PA146&dq=%22und+verful+endlich%22&source=bl&ots=tGTWnqYkBq&sig=ACfU3U06QWpVs0RbyP57LwZoQBkUb_Mg4g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwim2fOVyLbpAhXN2qQKHbzoD-UQ6AEwAnoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22und%20verful%20endlich%22&f=false) und der Autor meint *verfiel*, aber was heisst "verfallen auf die Kinder"? [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/verfallen_Verb) beschreibt keine Bedeutung für "verfallen auf".

Comment: Beim Duden unter 5.

Comment: *Verfallen auf* ist auch bei [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/verfallen) unter Bedeutung 5. Ich nehme außerdem stark an, dass *verful* wegen des Reimes mit *Schul* gewählt wurde.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Er verfiel auf die Idee eines Mittagsschläfchens.

So kann man das auch heute gut verwenden.

In der Geschichte funktioniert es, weil vorher "*auf Rettung **sann***" steht. Also hat er überlegt, dann kam ihm die (rettende) Idee mit den Kindern. Was genau, dazu muss man weiterlesen.

Man sieht den Lehrer ja wie er sich mit der Geste an die Stirn tippt.

---

Einer Sache (auch einer fixen Idee) verfallen (sein) ist was anderes.

---

> Da verfiel der Fuchs auf eine List.

Der dramaturgische Höhepunkt so mancher Fabel.